# How to import 'ember-routing/system/query_params' in an ember-cli app

Tags: ember.js

I think I do not understand well the modules hierarchy in an ember-cli app.

I need to

`import QueryParams from 'ember-routing/system/query_params';`

in one of my app services.

but the console shouts at me

`Error: Could not find module 'ember-routing/system/query_params' imported from 'my-app/services/menu'`

What path should I use to import this module ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you show us your project tree :)

Comment: just a common ember-cli app structure

Comment: Well, first of all, you can't start by `ember-routing` if your project start by `my-app`. You can have a complete path starting by `my-app` (the name you have picked for your project) or a relative path using `../name_of_the_previous_folder`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same thing; get the `QueryParams` class so I could create a higher-level `link-to` that accepted a query param key.

Luckily `QueryParams` is a really basic class: you can create your own (compatible for use in `{{link-to}}` version of it:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
const { Object } = Ember;

export default Object.extend({
  isQueryParams: true,
  values: null,
});
```

Taken from [QueryParams source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.6.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/query_params.js)

Comment: It is `values`, not `value` :p

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you got that path from [the Ember source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/query_params.js). Unfortunately, Ember's internal package structure is not exposed externally to other module loaders such as Ember-CLI's. As of now, the only way to access the Ember library and its internals is to import the main object from `ember` and use that.

```
// This...
import Ember from 'ember';
const Controller = Ember.Controller;

// Not this...
import Controller from 'ember-runtime/controllers/controller';
```

Unfortunately for you the `QueryParams` object is not exposed in this manner. However, that object is simply an implementation detail and I can't see a reason why you would need it in your app. I'm guessing you might be mistaken as to what that actually does. The [guide on query parameters](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/query-params/) might help you there.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to import from ember internals. But it is considered as hack.

```
const metal = Ember.__loader.require('ember-metal');
```

Above is how to import from `ember-metal` to import `ember-routing/system/query_params` review loader registry for proper import

```
const registry = Ember.__loader.registry
console.log(registry);
```